# Windows Mobile: распознавание устройства как внешнего программными средствами

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-ce

У меня есть внешнее Windows Mobile устройство (на базе ОС Windows CE 5.0). Когда я подсоединяю это устройство по USB к стационарному компьютеру оно распознается не как флешка, а как портативное переносное устройство, при этом открывается окно "Центр устройств Windows Mobile".
[image]

Мне необходимо перенести файлы с устройства на стационарный компьютер в автоматическом режиме. То есть на ПК работает моя программа, аналог "Центр устройств Windows Mobile", при подключение устройства она срабатывает и переносит файлы на компьютер.

Мне нужно:

1) Распознать событие подключения устройства;
2) Программно обратиться на это устройство и извлечь необходимые файлы.

Хочу узнать какая библиотека/функция/событие в Windows может за это отвечать. Есть ли примеры уже готового кода работы с переносными Windows Mobile устройствами.

В какой среде и на каком языке писать не критично, главное понять где такой функционал можно найти.
За любую более-менее подробную информацию буду крайне признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для того, чтобы получить событие подключения нового устройства существует WinAPI функция [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx). GUID для устройства `"Windows CE USB ActiveSync Devices"` равен `{25dbce51-6c8f-4a72-8a6d-b54c2b4fc835}`.
2. Для того, чтобы подсоединиться и извлечь файлы с устройства, существует библиотека [OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication](http://rapi.codeplex.com/)